# Mark left by laser pulse on spaceship

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Bob is travelling in a spaceship which is 10 meters long at uniform speed of 0.6c relative to Michael who is located on earth. Bob's spaceship is length contracted and it looks 8 meters long in Michael's frame of reference. By principle of symmetry and reciprocity, Bob notices that everything in Michael's frame of reference is also length contracted.

Both Bob and Michael are equipped with laser guns which emit cylindrical laser pulses in respective frames of reference. Bob would see Michael's laser gun length contracted and its bore appears to be an ellipse rather than circular. We assume that the laser pulse remains collimated and when it hits the spaceship, it leaves a mark on its surface.

Michael fires his laser gun. He sees a circular or cylindrical pulse moving toward the spaceship. Now, here is the troubling point. The pulse hits spaceship and leaves a mark. Would that mark appear to be an ellipse to Michael? If it does appear to be an ellipse to Michael, how could he explain it to himself that his circular pulse left an elliptical mark on the spaceship?

Answer (score 1):

Note that a "laser pulse" is a three-dimensional object. I'm assuming that your pulse is brief enough that the light pulse (in the rest frame of the emitter) has an aspect ratio like a coin, rather than a longer pulse from the same aperture where the volume of light would be shaped more like a cigar or an uncooked spaghetti strand.

I won't solve the problem for you entirely, because of our [guidelines on homework-ish questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/44126).  But I'll tell you the shape of the solution.  You have *four* events that have to be located in spacetime:

1. The laser pulse is emitted from the forward ("bow," to a sailor) end of Michael's gun.
2. The laser pulse is emitted from the aft ("astern"?) end of Michael's gun.
3. The edge from #1 makes a mark towards the stern of Bob's spacecraft.
4. The edge from #2 makes a mark towards the bow of Bob's spacecraft.

Both Michael and Bob agree that the ships are parallel.  In Michael's reference frame, events 1,2 are simultaneous, and events 3,4 are simultaneous.  But in Bob's reference frame, the two emission events are *not* simultaneous, because ["simultaneous" only happens in one reference frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity). Likewise, in Bob's reference frame, there is a non-zero delay between events 3,4.

You have to figure out what this delay is, and how it is related to the length contraction across the aperture of the laser emitter, in order to figure out the aspect ratio of the mark made by Michael's laser on Bob's ship.  Then you have an additional coordinate transformation to decide whether Michael sees the mark on Bob's ship as a circle or as an ellipse (and if as an ellipse, which way the long axis goes).

Comment: Thank you but it's not a homework problem. I'm doing self-study and was just curious. I don't want to use Minkowski spacetime; one I don't like it and second I don't understand it at all. I hope there is a way to solve it without the spacetime. It can be assumed that the pulse is of infinitesimal duration and looks like a coin with diameter of 20 cm and depth/thickness dz in the rest frame of Michael. How can the events "1" and "2" simultaneous if the depth is of considerable size? First, the upper side of the 'coin' pulse leaves the gun, and then it's the bottom side.  **Cont'd**

Comment: In other words, upper and bottom side of 'coin' pulse leave the gun at different times. Yes, if the thickness of 'coin' pulse is assumed to be infinitesimal, then it can be approximated that two events are simultaneous. If Bob's spaceship is moving along x-axis then Michael's original 20 cm wide infinitesimally thin coin pulse would be length contracted along the x-axis and would look like an ellipse with 20 cm major axis along y-axis and minor axis 16 cm along x-axis. I still cannot find a way to visualize how a circular pulse leave an elliptical mark on the spaceship for Michael.

Comment: Your comments make me wonder whether we are using the same names for all of the directions involved.  In person I could talk you through it, but we would end up making a spacetime diagram together. If you're not ready for spacetime diagrams yet, you'll have a hard time convincing yourself to trust any answer to this question.  I suggest you collect enough reputation to use [chat], then politely ask whether anyone in there would be willing to have a back-and-forth with you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any book where such a problem is solved? I would like to understand it because this is something I personally consider really important to me. Minkowski spacetime is later addition to the SR so I'm sure there must be a way to find an answer without using spacetime.

Comment: @PG1995 try this https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm if you want to know about aberration of light.

Answer (score 1):

Actually @Rob provides good guidelines. However, we can do well without any intricate diagrams but some other details must be considered. The mark may be $\gamma$ times contracted, or $\gamma$ times stretched or even of the same round shape, that depend on which angle the “shooter” inclines his laser gun.

Let's consider the following scenarios:

*The light pulse was received when Michael and Bob were at points of closest approach.*

Let's say that Michael is “at rest” and fires laser pulse towards Bob at right angle towards direction of Bob’s motion. Micheal must do that some time before Bob's arrival to their (frame independent) points of closest approach since it takes time for the light to cover distance between spaceships. The edges from the laser gun simultaneously depart in the Michael’s frame and simultaneously (in Michael’s frame) hit Bob’s spacecraft. Due – to Lorentz contraction of the Bob’s spacecraft the mark would appear $\gamma$ times stretched in the Bob's frame. Michael can see himself the stretched mark if Bob finally stops.

Good to note, that laser pulse that was emitted at right angle in Michael’s frame due to aberration of light would approach Bob at oblique angle “from the front”.
Bob may give (at least) twofold explanation of the “stretched” mark:

1)  I was moving in the Michael’s frame and my spaceship was Lorentz- contracted; that’s why I see the mark is $\gamma$ times stretched;

2)  Michael was moving in my frame and the edges of the mark left his laser pointer at different moments and from different distance; that’s why I see the mark as stretched.

*The light pulse was emitted when Michael and Bob were at points of closest approach.*

Let's consider another setup - Michael considers that he is moving in the frame of the Bob himself and emits laser pulse with the aim to hit Bob. In this case, when both Michael and Bob are at (frame – independent) points of closest approach Michael fires his laser (so as to take into account aberration of light) backward and this laser pulse would approach Bob at right angle. In this case the mark would appear $\gamma$ times contracted.

This picture may also have twofold explanation and both Michael and Bob may speculate about simultaneity of events.

Speaking about simultaneity I mean that every participant employs standard (Einstein’s) definition of simultaneity in his own "rest" frame.

It should be noted, that non - standard definition of simultaneity is also - self consistent.

One can draw some parallels between your problem and relativistic photography; for some details please look [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312494874_THE_TERRELL-PENROSE_ROTATION_WHEN_PHOTOGRAPHING_A_SPHERE_AT_REST_WITH_A_MOVING_CAMERA) or [there](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1251/1/012035)

[Simplified analysis is here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304794967_Photographing_using_relativistic_camera_-obscura)

Comment: _"Due – to Lorentz contraction of the Bob’s spacecraft the mark would appear γ times stretched in the Bob's frame. Michael can see himself the stretched mark if Bob finally stops."_ Imagine that Michael is standing 'stationary' in his frame of reference and Bob's spaceship is approaching him from the left. As Michael's knows the speed of spaceship is 0.6c and it's flying at height of 0.6c second therefore he can easily calculate what time he needs to fire vertically so that the pulse could hit spaceship. There is a problem. **Cont'd**

Comment: Typically, it is said that Michael would see Bob and spaceship length contracted and Bob would also see Michael and his surroundings length contracted in the direction of motion. Does Bob's view of length contraction of Michael and his surroundings change with Bob's distance from Michael's location? You said that Bob would see the laser pulse mark stretched then wouldn't it contradict Bob's 'earlier' view of length contraction of Michael and his surrounding where Bob sees Michael and gun's bore opening contracted? How could Bob convince himself that a stretched mark could result  **Cont'd**

Comment: from a length contracted elliptical gun bore?

I believe Michael would see the mark as a circle.

_"2) Michael was moving in my frame and the edges of the mark left his laser pointer at different moments and from different distance; that’s why I see the mark as stretched."_ Doesn't Bob know that how a laser gun emits a pulse?! If Bob thinks that the edges of laser pulse left the gun's bore at different times, we might as well conclude that Bob had never see a laser gun before! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Lorentz - stretched object is nothing surprising. Will an object appear "Lorentz - contracted" or "Lorentz elongated" purely depend on how an observer adjusts tools and interprets measurements - turns his laser pointer (or gaze), or synchronizes clocks in his frame. SR recognizes only one definition of simultaneity - Einstein's while there are infinitely many clock synchronizations (non-standard). In SR Bob would never confess that he was moving himself in Michael's frame; he would say that Michael was moving in his frame (look for explanation #2) and will only accept corresponding explanation

Comment: When we deal with visual appearance we must also consider light propagation delay from different parts of the object, simultaneity of emission of light from different parts of the object. In that case if photoemulsion is moving we should also add effect of motion of the film (it may smear the image in some cases) and Lorentz - contraction of emulsion itself. It takes some time to properly chew it but it is not too complex. I's recommend this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304794967_Photographing_using_relativistic_camera_-obscura because it resembles with your problem.

Comment: Another important concept is conventionality of distant simultaneity; one should understand that "standard" or "Einstein's" simultaneity is only a special case of broader "non-standard". Einstein's synchrony is in accordance with "state of rest"; anisotropic is in accordance with state of "motion". If "moving observer" uses "anisotropic" synchrony convention then an object "at rest" would appear to him not contracted, but $\gamma$ times elongated; but SR rules out any synchronization except Einstein's https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_conv_sim/index.html

Comment: _"Lorentz - stretched object is nothing surprising. Will an object appear "Lorentz - contracted" or "Lorentz elongated" purely depend on how an observer adjusts tools and interprets measurements - turns his laser pointer (or gaze), or synchronizes clocks in his frame. SR recognizes only one definition of simultaneity - Einstein's while there are infinitely many clock synchronizations (non-standard)"_ I'm assuming standard clock synchronization and definition of simultaneity. Well, it is always said that if a spaceship A is 10 meters long and moving at speed 0.6c, it would look **Cont'd**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106734/discussion-between-pg1995-and-albert).